# How can I correct UTM coordinates using distance and azmuth (AKA angle)?

Tags: r

I have a series of UTM coordinates that I have to correct based on known distance and azmuth (angle) to the corrected location.  UTMs are based on 1-m-resolution grids, which should make calculations relatively easy.

The data look something like this, where all x and y values are positive and all the azmuths are positive compass bearings 0-359 (running clockwise, where N=0 and S=180).

```
obs.1<-c(3,4,3,90)
obs.2<-c(3,4,2,180)
obs.3<-c(214,318,15,177)
fake.data<-data.frame(rbind(obs.1,obs.2,obs.3))
colnames(fake.data)<-c("x","y","dist","azmuth")
fake.data
```

I'd like to write a script in R to automate this correction.  Graphing it out is easy for easy numbers: corrected obs.1 convert to x.corrected=6,y.corrected=4 and obs.2 should convert to x.corrected=3,y.corrected=2, but you have to get into some trig when dealing with more complex numbers like in obs.3.

Here's my sorry attempt to automate the answer; it doesn't produce the correct results based on my simple graphical solutions. Help much appreciated

```
fake.data$x.corrected<-fake.data$x + fake.data$dist*cos(fake.data$az)
fake.data$y.corrected<-fake.data$y + fake.data$dist*sin(fake.data$az)
fake.data
```

Comment: UTM coordinates don't use lat/longs. They are represented by Eastings and Northings on a Cartesian plane with units of metres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues here. First, the `cos()` and `sin()` functions work in radians, not degrees. So you need to covert like so:

```
fake.data$azmuth<--1*(fake.data$azmuth)*pi/180
```

So, now you can do the trigonometry correctly. However, I don't get the answers you expect, as I think you got the sines and cosines mixed up and need to subtract for the `x` rather than add. This should give you the output you are looking for:

```
    fake.data$x.corrected<-fake.data$x - fake.data$dist*sin(fake.data$azmuth)
    fake.data$y.corrected<-fake.data$y + fake.data$dist*cos(fake.data$azmuth)
```

Note: I didn't go and look  up these formulas - I just made them match your expected output so you should double check and test them on a few more cases.